# Why are unknown instuctions there in a file generated by objdump?

Tags: assembly, objdump, thumb

I dumped an object file using 'objdump', and found wierd instructions (unknown instructions).
The following shows that wierd part.

[image]

The object file is built with thumb-2 compile option.
So, you can find normal 16-bit and 32-bit instructions from line 0x524 and 0x56c.
But, from line 0x570 to line 0x580, there are instructions I can not found in the reference manual (e.g. http://class.ece.iastate.edu/cpre288/resources/docs/Thumb-2SupplementReferenceManual.pdf).

What are they? and How can I interpret those instructions?

Comment: Presumably just embedded data (literal pool). Notice the code branches away before reaching that part.

Comment: objdump is simply disassembling whatever it finds, instructions, data,  string tables, whatever, so you are just seeing data.  The unconditional branch is an indicator as well as you probably have pc relative reads of those items after that branch somewhere in the code above.